# sqlazure not able to login

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

[ScriptObject_TypeDoesNotExist]
Arguments: XMLHttpRequest
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=8.1.10411.0&File=System.Windows.Browser.dll&Key=ScriptObject_TypeDoesNotExist
Parameter name: typeName

i m getting this error when i m trying to log into the SQL azure

Answer (score 0):

This error message is not related with SQL Database at all, instead it shows some issue with your run time.

Based on the error message, I am guessing that you trying to connect SQL Database from a SL application or something similar. Based on this error it could be specific to SL run time and you may not have proper runtime to start with. Have the latest run time to get past this error.